# Describe all the injective funktions from X to Y

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Let $X = \{1,0\}$ and $Y=\{2,3,4\}$
Describe all injective functions from $X$ to $Y$.

I kind of understand the basics of injective fuctions, that each $x$ has a unique value in $Y$, but I'm not sure how to work with this exercise. I'm not necessarily looking for an answer to the exercise, but an example or explanation on how to solve on this kind of exercise.

Thank you.

Comment: What exactly are you having trouble with? Start with writing out some function $X \rightarrow Y$ and see if they are injective.

Comment: You are right that injectives means only one x for each x. Now, you only have 2 elements in X, so they can only be mapped to two elements in Y. Can you take it from here?

Comment: If $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is a function. Then $f(0)$ is $2,3$ or $4$. Thus there are three possible values for $f(0)$. Similarly, $f(1)$ is $2,3$ or $4$. Thus there are only $9$ functions from $X$ to $Y$ and you can explicitly write them down. You only have to figure out which ones are injective and which ones aren't.

Comment: I see. I think I understand it better now. That was also something I wasn't sure of, how many functions there were from $X$ to $Y$. That was helpful, thank you.

Comment: Do you know the pigeonhole principle? A trivial but subtle application here.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

- How many elements will be in the image of $X$, given that $f$ is injective?
- How many injective functions are there from $X$ to $\{2,3\}$, and which ones are there?

If you can answer these two questions, you should be able to answer the full question.